# Using LEFT JOIN in an embedded query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Here is the query I'm having a problem with:

```
UPDATE entry SET is_locked_by = NULL
WHERE id IN (
              SELECT cee."entryId" FROM category_entries_entry AS cee
              WHERE cee."categoryId" IN (${descendantsWithParent.map(c => c.id).join()})
              LEFT JOIN category cat ON cee."categoryId" = cat.id WHERE NOT cat.is_locked
            );
```

Category relates to Entry as ManyToMany. And I want to update all entries where `category.is_locked` is `false`.

This query does not seem to work, it seems to ignore the `WHERE NOT cat.is_locked`.

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: The two `WHERE` clauses in the inner query look sketchy

Comment: join can not be used after where clause. it seems you are mixing function operator of JS in postgres query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no  problem with `WHERE NOT cat.is_locked` as long as `is_locked` is `boolean`.
You should write your query like this.

```
UPDATE entry SET is_locked_by = NULL
WHERE id IN (
              SELECT cee."entryId" FROM category_entries_entry cee
              LEFT JOIN category cat ON cee."categoryId" = cat.id
              WHERE NOT cat.is_locked 
              and cee."categoryId" IN ( set of IDs)  -- you can use your statement in your program i. e. (${descendantsWithParent.map(c => c.id).join()}
            );
```

Comment: Aah yeah seem so. Thank you, lemme check if it works.

Comment: your value list should be proper after `IN`